# Deallocating 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

For whatever reason I am getting the following error when trying to free the 2D array I created:

> Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001759310 *** Aborted (core dumped)

I printed out the contents of the array and they are correct and I am able access all of the elements. However, I am yet to be able to free it. The error occurs when going through the freeing loop, i.e. freeing double *. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
/*allocation*/
double **block_mat = (double **) malloc (sizeof(double *) * num_blocks);
int i;
for (i = 0; i <num_blocks; i++){
    block_mat[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double) * s);
}

/*freeing*/
for (i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++){
    free(block_mat[i]);
}
```

free(block_mat);

EDIT:
The error was found! I under-allocated memory...So when I printed out my arrays they looked like everything was fine... I allocated arrays of sizes s, but used s^2 instead. Thank you everyone!

Comment: The code as posted looks fine, apart from the redundant/dangerous casts - try to put together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the type and value of `s`?

Comment: s is an int...  as I have said I can also access all the elements of the list.

Comment: Try using calloc to define your arrays, it's definitely more correct.

Comment: By what definition, @rhubarbdog?

Comment: Could you please explain about the casts? I am just learning C and not sure I understand what you mean. Also the professor told us to use malloc, but I can try calloc as well...

Comment: The code looks correct. I tried it in a simple main(), with num_blocks = 50 and s = 100 and it doesn't crash. Try to post an entire program, with info on your platform (OS and libc version) because it might be a bug somewhere else than in your code.

Comment: Also you should check the return value of all your malloc calls, because if one fails, then your program will crash.

Comment: I updated the code... Looping over the elements of the block_mat I get all of the elements as they are supposed to be.

Comment: Also I've read all over SO about why you should never cast the returned result of malloc, can't remember the rationale but worth reading.

Comment: Also consider a better compiler, I get a number of errors and warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot choose a compiler...we are using  sagemathcloud... so I get what I get =(

Comment: What the... `strtol()` is a C++ function. You should clarify whether you're using C or C++.

Comment: @Olga Kazakova. I think one problem may be that you should not use free(matrix) before to free its fields!

Comment: strtol() can be used in C... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm

Comment: @Olga Kazakova. Another comment that may remain my idea is that if you're using ** you have a "project" error!

Comment: I actually initially did it the right way... but then I started moving things around in all possible combinations.. If comment out the freeing of block_mat[i] everything works fine

Comment: @SergioFormiggini could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc (in C)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Olga Kazakova. I understand you manage a bi-dimensional rectangular matrix! You might use a vector of double and manage it as a matrix! vector[x * ny+y]! You may use double * vector=malloc(nx * ny * sizeof(double)) ... etc, etc.

Comment: Are you sure `block_index` doesn't get larger than `s`? This could lead to an out-of-bounds write

Comment: @Olga Kazakova. Regarding the issue relevant to  block_mat[i], are you sure you don't use it after it's freed?

Comment: @Mints97 nope... it gets to s*s as it should and the last time it writes is at [s*s-1]

Comment: @SergioFormiggini most definitely=) it is the last line of my code=)

Comment: @Mints97 - that you so much!!!! you were correct!!! I intended the size to be s^2 but allocated on s!!!! ERROR IS FOUND=)

Comment: @PaulR that you very much too! Putting an MCVE helped me see what I did wrong since I threw out everything I did not need!

Comment: @Mints97 ok then, if you write that as an answer, she can mark it as correct and you both get reputation points

Comment: @Tobia: MOehm discovered the same problem and put it in his nice answer, which deserves to be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate space for `s` doubles for each `block_mat[i]`. Later, you access

```
block_mat[i][block_index] = 0;
block_index++;
```

but you never check that `block_index` goes out of bounds, which it does.

If you write beyond the `s` allocated doubles, you might corrupt the internal control data for the subsequent pointer, which usually is placed before the pointer returned by `malloc` and which is required to be intact by `free`.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered it literally a second before you posted=) Thank you though! That absolutely was THE problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that these pointers were all allocated with distinct mallocs?

```
free(my_matrix->vals);
free(my_matrix->cols);
free(my_matrix->rows);
free(my_matrix);
for (i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++){
    free(block_mat[i]);
}
free(block_mat);
```

If two of them are the same pointer, then you are trying to free something twice.

Comment: yes... my_matrix was allocated by a different function.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
free(my_matrix);
free(my_matrix->vals);
free(my_matrix->cols);
free(my_matrix->rows);
```

The order should be at least like this:

```
free(my_matrix->vals);
free(my_matrix->cols);
free(my_matrix->rows);
free(my_matrix);
```

Comment: yup! Thank you! But that does not solve the issue with the block_mat =(

Comment: What happen if you move `free(my_matrix)` etc below `block_mat` clean-up ?

Comment: still fails... unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You have several problem that can impact allocation. The first, what if the call to `strtol` fails?

```
    s = (int)strtol(argv [3], &ptr, 10);
```

You should check the conversion:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
else {
    errno = 0;
    long tmp = strtol(argv [3], &ptr, 10);
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (tmp == LONG_MIN || tmp == LONG_MAX)) ||
        (errno != 0 && tmp == 0)) {
        perror ("strtol");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ptr == argv[3]) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s = (int)tmp;
}
```

Next, with your allocation and free, you were on the right track, but **don't cast the return of malloc**. Casting the return only increases the chance of a hard to debug error. When allocating a pointer-to-pointer-to-double, you need to allocate as many pointers as needed. (`num_blocks`) in your case. When computing the size of the allocation, you can simply dereference the variable being allocated which again lessens the chance of error:

```
int i;
double **block_mat = malloc (sizeof *block_mat * num_blocks);
/* check allocation for failure */

for (i = 0; i <num_blocks; i++){
    block_mat[i] = malloc (sizeof **block_mat * s);
    /* check allocation for failure */
}

/*freeing*/
for (i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++){
    free (block_mat[i]);
}
free(block_mat);
```

**Note:** you must initialize all values in `block_mat` before you begin referencing the elements to prevent the deference of an unassigned value later. (e.g. `double result = block_mat[i][j] * Pi;`) Consider adding:

```
    block_mat[i] = malloc (sizeof **block_mat * s);
    /* check for failure */
    block_mat[i] = 0.0;
```

**Note:** When allocating numerical matricies, consider using `calloc` instead of `malloc` as it will initialize all values to `'0'` and prevent the inadvertent dereference of an unassigned valued -- which is **undefined behavior**. Using `calloc` you would have:

```
int i;
double **block_mat = calloc (num_blocks, sizeof *block_mat);
/* check allocation for failure */

for (i = 0; i <num_blocks; i++){
    block_mat[i] = calloc (s, sizeof **block_mat);
    /* check allocation for failure */
}

/*freeing*/
for (i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++){
    free (block_mat[i]);
}
free(block_mat);
```

**Note:** when `s` is greater than `1`, you will alloc space for more than one double at each pointer. Noting prevents you from doing that, but you are responsible for **handling the offset to each value**. (e.g. `result = *(block_mat[i] + j + n * sizeof **block_mat) * Pi;`, where n is `0 <= n < s`) If you are storing multiple doubles in each pointer, consider using a `pointer-to-struct` instead. E.g.:

```
typedef struct point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} point;
```